# Mixing v0.4.x contracts and v0.5.x contracts in Truffle possible?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

Is it possible to deploy contracts with truffle that do not all follow the same pragma?

I'm trying to deploy a solidity 0.4.10 contract alongside a solidity 0.5.0 contract in one truffle project. I defined my solc as 0.5.0 in truffle.js.

Answer (score 0):

With the [breaking changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html) in Solidity v0.5.0 this is not possible since you are utilizing the v0.5.0 compiler with Truffle. You should consider upgrading your old contract to utilize the latest pragma and follow the latest syntax.

If you have an old contract that you need to interface with, you can utilize the [interoperability pragma](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html#interoperability-with-older-contracts).